# Why do certain coordinates (latitude and longitude) not work with the Google Maps SDK for iOS API?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-street-view

I'm using the Google Maps SDK for iOS. I have this code below in order to pull up a panoramic street view of coordinates:

```
override func loadView() {
    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectZero)
    panoView.delegate = self
    self.view = panoView
    panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.000,150.312))
}
```

While I understand why (0,150.312) isn't valid since it's just ocean, why are other coordinates like "39.539, -89.938" not valid. These are coordinates for a place in Illinois which has street view available on maps.google.com. Is there a reason behind what locations work on the Google Maps SDK for iOS?

If there's no reason behind what addresses work/don't: does anyone have any suggestions for workarounds or alternatives to google maps api? (something that will take in coordinates and return a street view of what it looks like/map view)

Comment: Hello, did you ever find an answer to this problem because it keeps happening to me and it's random.

Comment: To the end user, Google is god. To the developer, Google is a regular dude. Btw, could Google's API Swift documentation be any worse?

Answer (score -1):

I am working with the Google Maps API myself and admit that I am not an expert on this API. However, it looks like you have to mix the streetview panorama with the 'generic' maps view for the case if the lat/long coordinates do not work for the street view. Im currently researching a way to find which lat/long coordinates work for the steetview panorama. I believe there should be some type of property that can detect which coordinates work or don't.

Comment: The answer does not contribute to a solution. However, as suggested, could include a comment instead of answering.